# How to configure role to edit only specific nodes by field?

Tags: entities, users, nodes

I have a content type named "Event". I created a field named "Type" so I may create different kinds of Events (eg. Courses, Lectures, Conferences).
The problem is that each type of Event is administered by different people. And one is not allowed to edit other's content.
How is the best way to do this?
Or is it better to create a content type for each type of event?

Comment: The biggest question you should ask yourself is how many people will be administering each event (i.e. do you need roles)? And how many different types of events will be (i.e. will you need many different content types). 
Depending on your scale you'll probably have a good idea what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an ideal case for one of the Taxonomy access modules.

There are several to choose from, though I favour 
[Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) as it also allows you to grant access to individuals (should the need arise) as well as giving access rights based on roles.

The basic setup would be:-

1. Create a Taxonomy of the different kinds of event that you wish to use.
2. Give each "Event" node a Taxonomy reference field, that references the values from the Taxonomy that you setup in step 1.
3. Install and activate [Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) via your preferred method.
4. Configure the access for each role to the Taxonomy from step 1. via the TAC lite configuration screen.  There are options to control the viewing, updating, and deletion of nodes, as well as the visibility of the Taxonomy terms in selection lists - which prevents users creating nodes tagged with event types that they don't have access to.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create less number of content types, as too many content type does not a good authoring experience.

But its very important to identify which content types can be merged to one, its better to have a vision before you do this, Why?

- Because content type is like a folder to files, you would like to keep same kind of files in one folder, as an example you would not like to mix your finance files with HR.
- If you see huge difference in types of fields and configuration on your events, its better to have different content types, rather than one.

Again in case it just a difference of few fields you can easily manage them by
[field permission module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). It gives you permission at field level as which field can be accessed by which role.

And as @Jabelpeeps said Event type can be a taxonomy field, field options for which can be configured to use as per user role using [Taxonomy simple access](https://www.drupal.org/project/tsa) module.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use Taxonomy Access Control Lite. However, I'm also using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module which makes the tac_lite module not work properly. To resolve the issue, I created a custom module to do this:
    
`function trt5_glue_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
    global $user;
    if(!is_string($node)) {
        if (module_exists('tac_lite')) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= variable_get('tac_lite_schemes', 1); $i++) {
                $config = _tac_lite_config($i);
                if (in_array('grant_' . $op, $config['perms'])) {
                    $tids = _tac_lite_get_terms($node);
                    foreach($tids as $tid) {
                        $user_tids = _tac_lite_user_tids($account, $i);
                        if(!in_array($tid, $user_tids))
                            return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}`